# how to use filechannel as argument to write object

Tags: java, file

In my homework

```
writePosting(FileChannel fc, PostingList posting)
```

It seems to use fc to write contents of a class postingList, where PostingList contain an integer and a List.

But I find fc could only write bytes?....I do not even understand, why we put FileChannel as a parameter rather than a inputStream?

Could it write directly an integter or string? thanks!

Comment: How is `PostingList` implemented? is [this one](https://github.com/whoward/VectorSpaceIndex/blob/master/src/index/PostingList.java) ?. And, also, can you elaborate a little bit more your question?

Comment: I have added some explanantion.

Comment: _Posting contain an integer and a List_ . And `PostingList` ?

Comment: Hi, I mean the class PostingList contains an integer and a LIST

Comment: To write the object how? Are you supposed to be using serialization?

Comment: @EJP If he is asking _Could it write directly an integter or string?_ I think the easiest way is using serialization, don't you think?

Comment: @rpax It doesn't matter what we think is the easiest way. What matters is what he is expected to be doing. There are a lot of possibilities. As posed, the question doesn't presently make sense. If I was setting an assignment about serialization I wouldn't be gumming up the works with FileChannels, and if it was about channels I wouldn't be gumming it up with serialization.

Comment: @EJP I was only trying to help

Comment: @user3495562 I suggest you show your instructor this page and ask them to comment, or decide whether the assignment needs further clarification. Some very senior people have commented most adversely here. Either you've omitted some important information yourself or your instructor has.

Comment: Thanks, I also feel weird why they put filechannel as a parameter in this function and I will aks them this afternoon and get feedback, thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you solved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish that using serialization.

Class `PostingList`:

```
public class PostingList<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 6893022784519772456L;
private Integer number;
private List<T> list;

public PostingList(Integer number, List<T> list) {
    super();
    this.number = number;
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "PostingList [number=" + number + ", list=" + list + "]";
}
}
```

writePosting:

```
public static void writePosting(FileChannel fc, PostingList<Integer> posting)
            throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        try {
            baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
            oos.writeObject(posting);
            oos.flush();
            byte[] postingBytes = baos.toByteArray();

            System.out.println("Bytes read: " + postingBytes.length);

            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(postingBytes.length);
            // prepare buffer to fill with data.
            buffer.clear();
            // write the bytes
            buffer.put(postingBytes);
            // prepare for writing
            buffer.flip();
            fc.write(buffer);
        } finally {
            if (oos != null) {
                oos.close();
            }
            if (baos != null) {
                baos.close();
            }
        }

    }
```

And an extra method, readPosting :

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    private static PostingList<Integer> readPosting(FileChannel fc)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        // Better to set this to a higher number
        byte[] barray = new byte[32];

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(32);
        int bytesRead = 0;

        while ((bytesRead = fc.read(buffer)) != -1) {

            buffer.flip();
            buffer.get(barray, 0, bytesRead);
            bos.write(barray, 0, bytesRead);
            buffer.clear();

            // for testing
            System.out.println(bytesRead);
        }
        // We write the bytes recovered to an object
        byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        Object obj = null;
        try {
            bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
            obj = ois.readObject();
        } finally {
            if (bis != null) {
                bis.close();
            }
            if (ois != null) {
                ois.close();
            }
        }
        return (PostingList) obj;
    }
```

And a little test in the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        PostingList<Integer> pl = new PostingList<Integer>(100, list);
        File f = new File("out.dat");

        RandomAccessFile raf = null;
        FileChannel fc = null;
        try {
            raf = new RandomAccessFile(f, "rw");
            fc = raf.getChannel();
            writePosting(fc, pl);
            fc.close();
            raf.close();

            raf = new RandomAccessFile(f, "r");
            fc = raf.getChannel();
            System.out.println(readPosting(fc));
            fc.close();
            raf.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (fc!=null) {
                try {
                    fc.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (raf!=null) {
                try {
                    raf.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Basically, this is reading/writing serialized objects into a file, but with `FileChannel` instead of the *classic* way.

EDIT:

Output:

```
Bytes read: 301
32
32
32
32
32
32
32
32
32
13
PostingList [number=100, list=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```